# Results of infinte scroll are prepending instead of appending

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm using the `will_paginate` gem to paginate a list of users on my user index page. This pagination is working properly, so that when I click for the users on page 2, I'm taken to those users.

However, I implemented 'infinite scroll' on another part of this site and it worked beautifully, so I wanted to do the same with the users index page. When I scroll down, I want the new users to appear at the bottom of the page 1 user table. Currently the issue I'm running into though is the users aren't being 'appended' at the end of the page 1 users, they're being 'pre-pended' above the page 1 users.

#### `index.html.erb - users`

```
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="main-box no-header clearfix">
        <div class="main-box-body clearfix">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table user-list">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th><span>User</span></th>
                  <th><span>Friends</span></th>
                  <th class="text-center"><span>Status</span></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
                <div id="all-users" >
                  <%= render @users %>
                </div>
                <div id="infinite-scrolling">
                  <%= will_paginate %>
                </div>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### `_user.html.erb`

```
<tbody>
  <% unless user == current_user %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= image_tag user.gravatar_url default: "retro" %>
        <%= link_to user.name, user_path(user) %>
      </td>
      <td><%= pluralize(user.friends.count, "Friend") %></td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <div id="friend-form">
          <%= render partial: 'friendships/friendships_status', locals: {user: user} %>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

#### Relevant CSS:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";

.....

.user-list tbody td .user-subhead {
    font-size: 0.875em;
    font-style: italic;
}
.user-list tbody td .user-link {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
a {
    color: #3498db;
    outline: none!important;
}
.user-list tbody td>img {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.table thead tr th {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.875em;
}
.table thead tr th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e7ebee;
}
.table tbody tr td:first-child {
    font-size: 1.125em;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.table tbody tr td {
    font-size: 0.875em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-top: 1px solid #e7ebee;
    padding: 12px 8px;
}
```

#### In case it's helpful:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
  end
end
```

I believe this issue relates to my CSS. When I look at the 'pre-pended' page 2 results, it appears they're not part of the `table user-list` class but are rather identified by their `all-users` id tag.

#### Edit to include Javascript:

#### `index.js.erb`

```
$('#all-users').append('<%= j render(@users) %>');
<% if @users.next_page %>
    $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@users) %>');
<% else %>
    $(window).off('scroll');
    $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
<% sleep 1 %>
```

#### `users.coffee`

```
jQuery ->
    if $('.pagination').length
        $(window).scroll ->
            url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')
            if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60
                $('.pagination').text("Fetching more users...")
                $.getScript(url)
        $(window).scroll
```

Comment: `<div id="all-users" >
                  <%= render @users %>
                </div>
                <div id="infinite-scrolling">
                  <%= will_paginate %>
                </div>` should not be direct child of table, might be the reason why inserted tbody doesn't show under thead :) What about the source generated (view:source in the browser )?

Comment: is there a reason you're rendering multiple tbody's? thead's th elements will expect to correspond with td elements in the rows of the tbody below them. Have you tried moving tbody outside of the _user partial, and just render a new tr row for each @user?

Comment: @GCyrillus I'm still shaky with CSS. Can you explain? When using the Chrome dev tools, the `<div id="all-users"></div>` elements are showing as children of the 'table-responsive' class whereas I want them to be children of the 'table user-list' class.

Comment: @user3834416 Great point. I just moved that out of the post partial and into the index (wrapping the 'all-users' div). However, still having the same issue.

Comment: you'll need to include the javascript that handles the infinite scroll for the above. The CSS isn't causing the issue.

Comment: @user3834416 Just added

Comment: If it helps, the devtools say the new results are inheriting from `body` whereas those inside the table are inheriting from `table.table.user-list`